# input увелечение/уменьшение на 1

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.si_form {
 margin-top: 15px;
    padding: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 90px;
    height: 20px;
    background:#000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 6px 6px 18px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.34);
 -moz-box-shadow: 6px 6px 18px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.34);
 box-shadow: 6px 6px 18px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.34);
}
.si_form2 {
    width: 90px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-left: -6px;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 6px 6px 0px -5px rgba(255,255,255,0.27);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 6px 6px 0px -5px rgba(255,255,255,0.27);
box-shadow: inset 6px 6px 0px -5px rgba(255,255,255,0.27);
}
input[id=si_input] {
 width: 75px;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0 10px;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="si_form">
  <div class="si_form2"></div>
  <input type="text" id="si_input" name="from" placeholder="От">
</div>
```

Как реализовать функцию увелечения/уменьшение значение в input на 1. При клике на стрелочки справа.

Comment: И что дальше с этим делать?

Comment: Я так понял, что ему не хватает правильного типа input'a, т.е. - `number`.

Comment: Исправил описание

Comment: С помощью js отлавливайте клик и в значение инпута представляйте результат минуса или плюса. Не понимаю в чем проблема

Comment: @Артем, нативный input number крайне плохо стилизуется, нужны красивости - придется костылить свой

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function setHandler(e){
  let input  = e.querySelector('.si_input'),
      arrows = e.querySelector('.arrows'),
      // Устанавливаем новое значение прибавляя новое значение
      update = num => input.value = (parseInt(input.value, 10) || 0) + num;
  
  if(input === null || arrows === null)
    return;
  
  // Навешиваем и слушаем события клика на раппер стрелочек
  // При клике, определяем на какую стрелочку нажали просто проверяя класс
  arrows.addEventListener('click', e => update(e.target.classList.contains('up') ? 1 : -1));
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  // It is alive!!!
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.si_form')).forEach(e => setHandler(e));
});
```

```css
.si_form {
 margin-top: 15px;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    width: 60px;
    height: 20px;
    background:#000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 6px 6px 18px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.34);
 -moz-box-shadow: 6px 6px 18px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.34);
 box-shadow: 6px 6px 18px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.34);
}

.si_input{
 width: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0 10px;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:18px;
}
.si_input:focus{
  outline: none;
}
.arrows div{
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 8px solid transparent;
}
.up{
  top: -4px; right: 5px;
  border-bottom-color: #2c7fb3!important;
  border-top: 0;
}
.up:hover{
  border-bottom-color: #455ab5!important;
}
.down{
  bottom: -4px; right: 5px;
  border-top-color: #2c7fb3!important;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
.down:hover{
  border-top-color: #455ab5!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="si_form">
  <input type="text" class="si_input" name="from" placeholder="От">
  <div class='arrows'>
    <div class='up'></div>
    <div class='down'></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="si_form">
  <input type="text" class="si_input" name="from" placeholder="От">
  <div class='arrows'>
    <div class='up'></div>
    <div class='down'></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="si_form">
  <input type="text" class="si_input" name="from" placeholder="От">
  <div class='arrows'>
    <div class='up'></div>
    <div class='down'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```